# How to retrieve default HandlerExceptionResolver instances in Spring 3.x?

Tags: java, spring, exception, default

The Javadoc says that [AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.html), [ResponseStatusExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/ResponseStatusExceptionResolver.html) and [DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.html) are enabled by default in the DispatcherServlet.

I am trying to create a `HandlerExceptionResolverComposite`, but I would like to retrieve the `HandlerExceptionResolver` instances enabled by default. I tried `@Autowired`, but unsuccessfully.

My current solution is:

```
@Configuration
public class ErrorHandling {

//  @Autowired
//  AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver amher;
//  
//  @Autowired
//  ResponseStatusExceptionResolver rser;
//  
//  @Autowired
//  DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver dher;

    @Bean
    HandlerExceptionResolverComposite getHandlerExceptionResolverComposite() {

        HandlerExceptionResolverComposite result
            = new HandlerExceptionResolverComposite();

        List<HandlerExceptionResolver> l
            = new ArrayList<HandlerExceptionResolver>();

        l.add(new AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver());
        l.add(new ResponseStatusExceptionResolver());
        l.add(new DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver());

        result.setExceptionResolvers(l);

        return result;

    }

}
```

My question is: how can I retrieve the `HandlerExceptionResolver` instances enabled by default? Is it an issue if I create my own instances?

Comment: Yes, but I have only tested one case.

Answer (score 1):

Found something in BeanFactoryUtils

```
Map<String, HandlerExceptionResolver> matchingBeans = BeanFactoryUtils
                    .beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(context, HandlerExceptionResolver.class, true, false);
```

Check the source of DispatchServlet and go to initHandlerExceptionResolvers() method, probably you can find out a way of getting all registered exception resolvers.

Thanks